# Eliminate sub elements in a huge list of strings as long as no duplicates appear

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge list of strings (~ 15000). Each string is unique in the list.
All strings have words inside, which are separated by a dot.
An algorithm shall do the following: The middle terms shall be eliminated, as long as no duplicates appear - middle term by middle term separately.

My code works only, if I have three elements in sum and this works fine. When I have more than one middle term, I have no idea how to handle each term separately - from left to right.

Any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd

def remove_middle_words(terms):
 df = pd.DataFrame({'terms': terms})
 df[['first_word', 'middle_word', 'last_word']] = df['terms'].str.split('.', expand=True)
 
 unique_first_last = df.groupby(['first_word', 'last_word']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
 unique_first_last['remove_middle'] = unique_first_last['count'] == 1
 
 df = df.merge(unique_first_last[['first_word', 'last_word', 'remove_middle']], on=['first_word', 'last_word'], how='left')
 df['new_terms'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['terms'] if not row['remove_middle'] else f"{row['first_word']}.{row['last_word']}", axis=1)
 
 return df['new_terms'].tolist()
#case3+4 ok
terms = ['A.B3.C4', 'A.B3.C5', 'A.B4.C6', 'A.B5.C6']
new_terms = remove_middle_words(terms)
print(new_terms)
```

Examples:

Case1 (not ok with code below):

- A.B1.C1.D1 --> A.D1
- A.B1.C1.D2 --> A.D2
  (both B1 and C1 could be eliminated)

Case2 (not ok with code below):

- A.B2.C2.D3 --> A.C2.D3
- A.B2.C3.D3 --> A.C3.D3
  (only B2 could be eliminated, because if C2/C3 were eliminated, A.D3 were duplicates)

Case3 (ok with code below):

- A.B3.C4 --> A.C4
- A.B3.C5 --> A.C5
  (B3 could be eliminated)

Case4 (ok with code below):

- A.B4.C6
- A.B5.C6
  (nothing can be eliminated, because if B4/B5 were eliminated, A.C6 were duplicates)

Case5 (not ok with code below)

- A.B10.C10.D1
- A.B20.C10.D1
- A.B20.C20.D1
  (nothing can be eliminated, because if either Bx oder Cx are eliminated, they were duplicates A.D1)

Case6a (not ok with code below)

- A.B100.C100.D100.D1 --> A.B100.D1
- A.B200.C100.D100.D1 --> A.B200.D1
  (C100 and D100 could be eliminated, with remaining of Bx the terms are unique)

Case6b (not ok with code below)

- A.B300.C200.D100.D1 --> A.C200.D1
- A.B300.C300.D100.D1 --> A.C300.D1
  (B300 and D100 could be eliminated, with remaining of Cx the therms are unique)

Comment: Do all strings have the same number of chunks? What is the max number of chunks? What if you have something like `['A.B1.C1.D1', 'A.B2.C1.D1', 'A.B2.C2.D1']`? Do you really need to use pandas?

Comment: Hi @mozway ... no, they don't have the same number of chunks. My code works for three chunks (one in the middle). For four chunks (two in the middle) it unfortunately doesn't work. There can appear more than four chunks ~10. The chunks in the middle could be checked one after another for the complete list, as long as there exist some.
No, pandas is not mandatory - feel free to suggest other solutions than pandas.

Comment: I'm sorry but the logic is still not clear to me. If you can have different numbers of chunks within the same list, then give clear examples of how they interact. Also you haven't addressed the above example. This seems like a non-trivial logic, so the more explicit you are the less time will be necessary trying to help you.

Comment: @mozway I described this in Case 5 now. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

terms = ['A.B3.C4', 'A.B3.C5', 'A.B4.C6', 'A.B5.C6', 
         'A1.B1.C1.D1', 'A1.B1.C1.D2', "D1",
        "A.B10.C10.D1", "A.B20.C10.D1", "A.B20.C20.D1", 
        "A.B100.C100.D100.D1", "A.B200.C100.D100.D1",
        "A.B300.C200.D100.D1", "A.B300.C300.D100.D1",
        ""    
        ]

def rem_mid_words(txt1):
    if "." in txt1:
        l1 = txt1.split(".")
        txt2 = f"{l1[0]}.{l1[-1]}"   # pos 0 term & . & (-1 =) last term 
        return txt2
    else:
        pass  # string does not contain "."

term_count = {rem_mid_words(txt1): 0 for txt1 in terms}  # initial counting dictionary
for x in terms:
    key = rem_mid_words(x)
    term_count[key] += 1

new_terms = [rem_mid_words(txt1) 
             if term_count[rem_mid_words(txt1)] < 2
             else txt1 for txt1 in terms]
print(new_terms)


# start of adjusted answer

def rem_one_word(txt1, len1, pos):
    # Example "A1.B2.C3.D4.E5"
    # pos       0. 1. 2. 3. 4
    # length    5
    # if len1 is 5 and pos = 1 then remove B2 and return A1.C3.D4.E5
    # otherwise return original txt1
    
    if txt1 != None and "." in txt1:
        l1 = txt1.split(".")
        if len(l1) == len1:
            txt1 = ".".join(l1[:pos] + l1[(1+pos):])
    return txt1

def word_len(txt1):
    if "." in txt1:
        return len(txt1.split("."))
    else: return 0

def shorten_words(terms):   # input list of strings
    # get longest word in terms of "."
    # iterate by reducing length by one and replace if count < 2

    max_len = max([word_len(txt1) for txt1 in terms])
    terms1 = terms
    for len1 in np.arange(max_len, 2, -1):
        print("string length", len1)
        for pos in (1 + np.arange((len1)-2)):
            print("pos", pos)
            temp_words = [rem_one_word(txt1, len1, pos) for txt1 in terms1]
            temp_count = {x: 0 for x in temp_words}
            for x in temp_words: temp_count[x] += 1
            terms2 = [temp_words[i] if temp_count[temp_words[i]] < 2
                      else terms1[i] for i in range(len(terms1))]
            terms1 = terms2
    return terms1

terms1 = shorten_words(terms)

for i in range(len(terms)):
    print(terms[i], "   ", terms1[i])
```

Comment: WOW !!! ... thats really impressive and is 99% of my preferred solution. Now, the middle terms are completely eliminated if the terms are still unique after processing. But is there a possibility to handle it, if the differentation is not made by the very left or right term, but one in the middle? See Case 6a and 6b. Very left and right word shall remain as they are then, and only the not needed in the middle shall be eliminated, without this one, which leads to the differentation. @ASW22

Comment: Thank you, added in a couple of functions to try to generalise it a bit more for cases 5 and 6. The algorithm is to find the longest word(s)  in terms of .".", then reduce these by one where possible. So if the longest word  is like x1.x2.x3.x4.x5, then we try to remove one of x2, x3 or x4 - if it does not duplicate another term of length 4 then we replace the original term with this term, so that the term reduces from length 5 to 4. Then repeat for terms of length 4 and length 3.